# Allocate a large block instead of many small?

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm reading a 2 MB word list with about 200 000 words into memory. To be able to index them I use a `char *` array. Since the words won't grow or shrink, is it better to read the whole file into one memory block and let the pointers point into that, rather than doing a `malloc()` for every word?

Comment: What are your criteria for being "better"? I think performance-wise the differences will be negligible. It is not possible to make generalizations. It's dependent on the target system and usage patterns probably. But I would bet that in overall it would not matter at all.

Comment: If you want to know, try. The performance benefit will depend on the access pattern of the algorithms that use the word list.

Comment: I would allocate small blocks if you are low on memory or one big block if your CPU is weak.

Comment: remember that what you see as contiguous memory isn't actually contiguous. if you make one big block, it will still end up being spread out all over the place at the hardware level.

Comment: @Jeremy Small blocks are likely to take *more* memory because of allocator overhead.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow I see, thx, I thought that memory fragmentation could cause malloc() to fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrary to some of the comments posted so far, if you are tight on memory, you should allocate a single large block.  This is because each `malloc()` you do has some overhead which is more or less fixed.  This overhead will be a few bytes per allocation, so many small allocations could have you losing half your memory to overhead.

If you care a lot about performance (speed), you should also use a single allocation.  It will improve locality and cache utilization, and reduce the number of system calls during startup and also teardown.

Comment: if the block is larger than a page size, won't allocating a single block decrease accessing speed?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow: Unless you can propose a mechanism by which this would happen, and some evidence to back that up, I don't think so.

Comment: Allocating a single block also reduces the risk of memory fragmentation. For example, the largest allocation that's ever "guaranteed" (I use this word loosely) to succeed is on the order of `M/N` where `M` is the total memory space size (virtual on most modern systems) and `N` is the current number of live allocations.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Are there resources or benchmarks about this topic?